# PHP Order of evaluation for boolean functions

Tags: php, callback

When creating a `function` with a `foreach` (or any possibly time consuming task) and a `boolean return`, will PHP wait for the `foreach` to complete before moving on?

Is there ever a time when PHP doesn't wait? For example, in jQuery when I write a similar function with an ajax request, I have to put all code in the ajax `callback` function or else it will fail.

Code example:

```
function is_true(){
   $arr = array(true,true,true,false);
   foreach($arr as $curr){
      sleep(200);
      if(!$curr){ return false; }
   }
   return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP will wait for the `foreach` to complete, but only when you call the function, not when the function is defined.